Exercise 2.19 in Isaacs's book on character theory
Here is the problem:

Let $E=\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\rangle$ be an elementary abelian group of order 16.Let $P=\langle y\rangle$ be cyclic of order 3.$P$ acts on $E$ by
$$x_1^y=x_2,x_2^y=x_1x_2,x_3^y=x_4,x_4^y=x_3x_4$$
Let $G$ be the semidirect product $E \rtimes P$.Show that $G$ does not have a faithful irreducible character.

With a hint:

The smallest possible degree for a faithful character of $E$ is 4.

The hint is easy to achieve,as all irreducible character of $E$ is linear.But I don't get the way to associate it with the question.Any advice would be helpful,thanks in advance.

What's the degree of a character?

@i can try It means $\chi(1)$.

You have already done the hard part, which is establishing the hint. You can now finish the problem in one line, using a previous problem from chapter 2. (As mentioned in the comments below, this is 2.9.)
Here is an ugly way to do the problem though. From the description of $G$, we can see there are $8$ conjugacy classes: the identity; $(|E|-1)/|P|=5$ coming from $P$ acting in $E$; and $(|P|-1)*16/|E|=2$ coming from $E$ acting on the $16$ Sylow $3$-subgroups. The description of the action of $P$ on $E$ also shows $E=[G,G]$, so there are $|G/E|=3$ linear characters of $G$.
If $d_1,\ldots,d_5$ are the degrees of the nonlinear characters, then we have
\begin{equation}
45 = d_1^2 + \cdots + d_5^2
\end{equation}
Assuming we have a faithful irreducible character, the hint shows the degree is at least $4$, and divides $G$. Let $d_1$ be this degree. The only possibilities are clearly $4$ or $6$. We're then left to solve one of the following two equations, where $d_i\ge2$:
\begin{align}
29 &= d_2^2+d_3^2+d_4^2+d_5^2\\
9 &= d_2^2+d_3^2+d_4^2+d_5^2
\end{align}
Neither of these has a solution, so the faithful irreducible character doesn't exist.

Oh,thanks a lot,I get it now.

Later in Isaacs' book ((6.19)Theorem) you will learn that the character degrees need to divide $|G:E|$, since $E$ is an abelian normal subgroup of $G$. So degrees $1$ and $3$ are the only possibilities.

Or use Problem (2.9)(b) of course. Even easier.

ah,I forgot (2.9).Appreciate your help indeed.
